# Using existing fields to name a new object - Java

Tags: java

How do I use an existing field to name another object/field?

```
String test = "test";

String 2;
```

I want the variable name of string 2 to be test2. How do I import the name of the first string into the name of the 2nd one?

Comment: You can't do that in Java. The best you can come up with is to create a `Map` of strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how would I do that? (Sorry I'm new to java)

Comment: You could potentially use reflection, and write the code at runtime, but: 1) That's **WAY** more work than you want to do, 2) There are large performance penalties for attempting it, 3) You require elevated security permissions, 4) It can be difficult to debug.  What is the problem you are trying to solve (variable names usually don't count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the variable name of string 2 to be test2.

Then name it `test2`. Type: "`String test2`" into your IDE.

> How do I import the name of the first string into the name of the 2nd one?

That's completely impossible. Variables names are determined at compiled time and can *not* be dynamic based on the content of another variable.

What you *might* be looking for is [`Map<String, Object>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that maps `String`s to `Object`s, but it's unclear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible with java, especially if you are using local variables. You cannot define variables given a name stored in a string, because there would thereafter be no way to refer to them.